# CodeIgniter - On click create table in database

Tags: codeigniter

I have an input field and a button. when I click on the button, a table must be created in the database, and its name should be the input from the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CONTROLLER:**

```
function create()
{
    $table = $this->input->post('table');
    $this->M_users->create($table);

}
```

**MODEL:**

```
function create($table)
{
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$table." (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(50),
  reg_date TIMESTAMP
  )";
  $query = $this->db->query($sql);
  return $query;
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('create');?>">
  <input type="text" name="table">
  <input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

If you want to do it with forge class, refer the following link:

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html

Comment: Thanks, Can i do this with using migration and dbforge also?

Comment: I'm not sure about that but I think you can.

Comment: If you are done with this code, please accept the answer.

Comment: @RedEye_0 : Yes, you can do this using dbforge class in codeigniter.

Comment: @RedEye_0 Please refer this [https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html)

Comment: @kishor10d: How can i do, can u send me code or explain?